# append list inside dictionary with update

Tags: python, list, dictionary, python-3.6

if i have below dictionary with one of the element is list, as follow:

```
myDict = dict(a=1, b='2', c=[])
```

how do I update myDict and at the same time append c

e.g.

```
myDict .update(a='one', b=2, c=append('newValue'))
myDict .update(a='1', b='two', c=append('anotherValue'))
```

and the final result should be:

```
myDict = a='1', b='two', c=['newValue', 'anotherValue']
```

in one statement....

Comment: Step 1: don't name your object `dict`

Comment: This is not a functionality that exists with [`dict.update()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.update).

Comment: thanks for the step 1

Comment: Why don't you just change the dict in two steps? First update `a` and `b` then append something to `c`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `append` within `update` because `append` is trying to perform an inplace operation on the dict value. Try list concatenation instead:

```
d = dict(a=1, b='2', c=[])
d.update(a='one', b=2, c=d['c'] + ['newValue'])
print(d)
{'a': 'one', 'b': 2, 'c': ['newValue']}
```

Or:

```
d.update(a='one', b=2, c=d['c'] + ['newValue'] + ['anotherValue'])
```